# Updating input fields with autoNumeric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am attempting to include autoNumeric.js into a calculator I have built. Using regular jquery, it works fine, but then when I attempt to inplement autoNumeric it breaks. This is my HTML

```
<form id="form1"           
   <input value="" type="text" class='t1'/> 
   <input value="" type="text" class='t2'/>
   <input value="" type="text" class='t3'/>
   <input value="" type="text" class='t4'/>
</form>`
```

So far I have the following scripts. One error i am noticing is that in my first input field, when I type anything over 999, input 4 is automatically `NaN`. My first input seems to do give me commas and decimals, but I cant seem to get the rest to work. Any suggestions would be great

```
$(".t1, .t2, .t3").change(function() {
  $(".t4").prop("readonly",
  true).autoNumericInstance($(".t1").autoNumericInstance() *  $(".t2").autoNumericInstance() * $(".t3").getNumber());
  });

    $('.t1, .t4').each(function() {
var autoNumericInstance = new AutoNumeric($(this)[0], AutoNumeric.getPredefinedOptions().dotDecimalCharCommaSeparator);
  });

$("input").autoNumeric('init', {
  aSep: '.',
  aDec: ',',
  aForm: true,
  vMax: '999999999',
  vMin: '0'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the old `1.9.*` syntax which needed jQuery as a dependency, with the latest jQuery-free autoNumeric version (currently v4.4.3).

You can also simplify your code quite a lot. Instead of doing:

```
$('.t1, .t4').each(function() {
    var autoNumericInstance = new AutoNumeric($(this)[0], 
        AutoNumeric.getPredefinedOptions().dotDecimalCharCommaSeparator);
});
```

just ditch jQuery and use:

```
const autoNumericInstancesArray = new AutoNumeric.multiple('.t1, .t4');
```

You whole code can be jQuery-free too by using:

```
const nodeArray = [... document.querySelectorAll('.t1, .t2, .t3')];
nodeArray.forEach(n => n.addEventListener('change', updateCalculator, false));

const [t1, t2, t3, result] = AutoNumeric.multiple('input', {
    digitGroupSeparator: '.',
    decimalCharacter: ',',
    formatOnPageLoad: true,
    maximumValue: '999999999',
    minimumValue: '0',
});
result.update({ readOnly: true });

updateCalculator() {
    result.set(t1.getNumber() * t2.getNumber() * t3.getNumber());
}
```

I haven't tested it in a live example (that you should have provided), but this should work.